# How to check that compactionn strategy is changed in cassandra?

Tags: cassandra

I'm changing compaction strategy from size to level? Is there any way to check whether the compaction has changed or not??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can find compaction info with query :**

For Cassandra Version < 3

```
SELECT compaction_strategy_class,compaction_strategy_options,max_compaction_threshold, min_compaction_threshold FROM system.schema_columnfamilies  WHERE keyspace_name = 'your_keyspace_name' AND columnfamily_name = 'your_table_name';
```

For Cassandra Version >= 3

```
SELECT compaction FROM system_schema.tables WHERE keyspace_name = 'your_keyspace_name' AND table_name = 'your_table_name' ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Login to cqlsh and check table structure.

```
$cqlsh> desc keyspacebname.tablename;
```

You will see the table compaction class:

```
CREATE TABLE keyspacebname.tablename (
    .....
    PRIMARY KEY (..)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (... DESC)
    AND bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
    AND caching = '{"keys":"ALL", "rows_per_partition":"NONE"}'
    ...
    AND compaction = {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy'}
    AND compression = {'sstable_compression': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
    ....
```

You can also check the compaction status via nodetool:

```
$> nodetool  compactionstats
```

for more details check these links: 
[nodetool compactionstats](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/tools/toolsCompactionStats.html)